# How to interpret the results of Oaxaca-Blinder decomposition? [Python]

Tags: python, decomposition, blinder-oaxaca

these are the results obtained for the square gap decomposition using the Oaxaca-Blinders method in Python:

Oaxaca-Blinder Three-fold Effects

Endowment Effect: -0.02663

Coefficient Effect: 0.19933

Interaction Effect: 0.05553

Gap: 0.22824

Oaxaca-Blinder Two-fold Effects

Unexplained Effect: 0.23207

Explained Effect: -0.00383

Gap: 0.22824

what does a negative value for the explained part mean?